# Is there a way to get to the stored queries for reports and graphs in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, catalog

We're using Tableau 10.5.6. I used a reporting tool years ago called Oracle Sales Analyzer. In that tool you could get to the queries generated by the reports and graphs you created through back-end catalogs using their command line.

There you could rewrite the query to be more efficient by fine-tuning the code if you needed. It was a very cool feature of that reporting tool for geeks like me who like to dive into the back end of the product and tune it at a very low level.

My question is, does Tableau have any of this type of facility? Is there a way to get to the queries that get stored once you create a report or a graph. Also is there command line where you can access these catalogs if they exist? Otherwise are these queries just stored in ASCII flat files that can be accessed by a user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that Tableau will query a database.

### Option 1: Custom SQL

In your data source, you paste in the sql you have written and Tableau will pass that query through to the database. This gives you complete control over the sql, including adding any indexing hints you may want. See https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.html

### Option 2: Use the Tableau data source designer

This is what many people do. Here, you visually design your data source with the joins. Tableau translates that design into what the Hyper engine considers to be the most effective way to run the query. Sometimes, Hyper translates that into a regular sql statement. Sometimes it does some additional things to help boost performance, like breaking it up into different queries. A lot depends on the db engine you are connecting to. There is no "sql" stored in a flat file for this. Tableau just translates your design at run-time. The Hyper engine does a good job with fine-tuning, assuming you have an efficient database design with proper indexing and current table statistics.

There is a way to see the sql from option 2 **at run-time** using [Performance Recording](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/perf_record_create_desktop.html). Performance Recording keeps track of each step of the visualization process and will spit out the sql statement(s) that Tableau ran to generate your dataset. The sql is not stored in the twb file though, it's a run-time analysis.